# Pooling logic does not execute in schedule (Laravel 8.20.1)

Tags: php, laravel, pool

I have a function in my Controller with a **pooling logic** using [Spatie/Async Library](https://github.com/spatie/async). Everything executes perfectly when the function is called via routing; but when called from a schedule (in app/Console/Kernel.php), the pool does not execute.

The same code runs without issues when tested locally using MAMP but not on production.

Here is the simplified version of my code:

**HomeController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Spatie\Async\Pool;
use Server;
use Ping;
use Setting;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    
    
    public function executePing()
    {
        $servers = Server::where('deleted', 0)->get();
        $concurrency = Setting::where('type', 'concurrency')->value('value');
        $ping_timeout = Setting::where('type', 'ping_timeout')->value('value');
        $pool = Pool::create()->concurrency($concurrency)->timeout($ping_timeout);
        
        //Save Pings
        foreach ($servers as $server)
        {
            echo "Starting Pool...";
            $pool->async(function () use ($server) {
                
                $new_ping = new Ping; //Line added after editing my question
                
                //Execute Ping
                echo "Ping Executed.";
            })->then(function ($output) {
                //Handle success
            })->catch(function (Throwable $exception) {
                //Handle exception
            });
            
        }
        await($pool);
        $data['data'] = "Executed";
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

**app/Console/Kernel.php**

```
namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected $commands = [
    //
    ];
    
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@executePing')->everyMinute()->runInBackground()->evenInMaintenanceMode();
    }
    
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');
        
        require base_path('routes/console.php' );
    }
}
```

Output when running **php artisan schedule:run**:

```
Running scheduled command: App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@executePing
Starting Pool...
```

Since I am using an external library, I had a hard time finding similar issues. If anyone may have a clue why this is happening or even an alternative to the library I used, it will be greatly appreciated.

**Important Edit:**

I noticed a lacking permission on the log file (stupid mistake). I fixed it and got the error.
What's happening is that all my Classes are not being recognized when called from inside the Pool. I can't declare any new objects or execute database queries. In the example above (edited after this update), I get:

```
local.ERROR: Class 'Ping' not found
#0 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/spatie/async/src/Runtime/ChildRuntime.php(26): App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::{closure}()
#1 {main} {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Class 'Ping' not found

#0 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/spatie/async/src/Runtime/ChildRuntime.php(26): App\\Http\\Controllers\\HomeController::{closure}()
#1 {main} at /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/spatie/async/src/Output/SerializableException.php:29)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/spatie/async/src/Process/ParallelProcess.php(122): Spatie\\Async\\Output\\SerializableException->asThrowable()
#1 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/spatie/async/src/Process/ProcessCallbacks.php(54): Spatie\\Async\\Process\\ParallelProcess->resolveErrorOutput()
#2 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/spatie/async/src/Pool.php(231): Spatie\\Async\\Process\\ParallelProcess->triggerError()
#3 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/spatie/async/src/Pool.php(327): Spatie\\Async\\Pool->markAsFailed(Object(Spatie\\Async\\Process\\ParallelProcess))
#4 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/spatie/async/src/Pool.php(153): Spatie\\Async\\Pool->Spatie\\Async\\{closure}(17, Array)
#5 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/spatie/async/src/helpers.php(22): Spatie\\Async\\Pool->wait()
#6 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php(1144): await(Object(Spatie\\Async\\Pool))
#7 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): App\\Http\\Controllers\\HomeController->executePing()
#8 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#9 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#10 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#11 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(66): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array)
#12 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(32): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callClass(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), 'App\\\\Http\\\\Contro...', Array, NULL)
#13 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(610): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), 'App\\\\Http\\\\Contro...', Array, NULL)
#14 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/CallbackEvent.php(80): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call('App\\\\Http\\\\Contro...', Array)
#15 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/ScheduleRunCommand.php(143): Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\CallbackEvent->run(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application))
#16 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/ScheduleRunCommand.php(102): Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\ScheduleRunCommand->runEvent(Object(Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\CallbackEvent))
#17 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\ScheduleRunCommand->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\Schedule), Object(Illuminate\\Events\\Dispatcher), Object(NunoMaduro\\Collision\\Adapters\\Laravel\\ExceptionHandler))
#18 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#19 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#20 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#21 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(610): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#22 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(136): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#23 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#24 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(121): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#25 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(971): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#26 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(290): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\ScheduleRunCommand), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#27 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(166): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#28 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(93): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#29 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#30 /home/website/web/website.com/public_html/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#31 {main}
"}
```

Comment: Stab in the dark, is the [PCNTL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php) extension installed on production?

Comment: Yes it's installed and enabled in php.ini

Comment: Notice: I edited my question with more details. I did the stupid mistake of not checking write permission for log file. Now I have the error and to put it simple: all classes "inside the pool" are not recognized when run from schedule (Kernel.php).